# ¿Como elijo el valor de un <select> que no tiene identificador pero si su <div>?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy usando la consola de Chrome para probar esto ya que lo usaría como script para ahorrar tiempo en una tarea que realizo.

La idea es la siguiente, yo tengo esto

```
<div id="seccion1">
    <select>
       <option value=1>Ejemplo 1</option>
       <option value=2>Ejemplo 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="seccion2">
    <select>
       <option value=1>Ejemplo 1</option>
       <option value=2>Ejemplo 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

En tonces yo quiero que el select de seccion1, cuando se cargue la app, desde el navegador y con la consola settear el valor del select, el tema es que al no tener ID propio, no puedo usar el getElementById, realmente no se como hacer. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 6):

Usa el método [QuerySelector](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp).

Ejemplo: `document.querySelector("#seccion1 > select").value=1`

Obtiene el primer elemento "select" en el documento donde su padre tiene el id "seccion1".

Answer (score 4):

Con **jquery** lo puedes hacer así:

```
var select = $("#seccion1 select");
```

Revisa el ejemplo:

```js
var select = $("#seccion1 select");

alert(select.text());

//Una vez que tenga el objeto ya puedes hacerle las modificaciones que desees:

$(select).css('width','250px');
$(select).css('height','30px');
$(select).css('color','blue');
$(select).append('<option value=3>Ejemplo 1.3-Agregado</option>');
$(select).append('<option value=4>Ejemplo 1.4-Agregado</option>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="seccion1">
    <select>
       <option value=1>Ejemplo 1.1</option>
       <option value=2>Ejemplo 1.2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="seccion2">
    <select>
       <option value=1>Ejemplo 1</option>
       <option value=2>Ejemplo 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comprobado si acepta **jquery** *Chrome*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta versión es la que estoy utilizando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que no estoy seguro que la consola de Chrome corra jQuery, o si?

Comment: Creo que si lo corre... haz la prueba :-)

Comment: Mira si lo corre, pero no se si dependa de si el jquery ya había sido cargado por la pagina abierta... tal vez dependa de eso.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x=document.querySelector("#seccion1 > select");
console.log(x);
```

```html
<div id="seccion1">
    <select>
       <option value=1>Ejemplo 1</option>
       <option value=2>Ejemplo 2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="seccion2">
    <select>
       <option value=1>Ejemplo 1</option>
       <option value=2>Ejemplo 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```